# Can I develop wear os app using android studio for Samsung watch5 and install in it by BT and Play store

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, watch, samsung-galaxy-watch

I am developing Wear OS app using android studio. Currently using Wear OS emulator for app development. I am planning to purchase Samsung Watch5 for development purpose.

I wonder if Watch5 will support android studio Wear OS apps installation from BT, USB and then can I download the same app from play store to Watch5 ?

Note: My wear app will be standalone. It wont require mobile phone to connect with watch5. Watch5 will not be connected to mobile phones. Watch will have internet from Wifi or any other LTE option.

Can anyone let me know ?

Comment: As I know, Samsung Galaxy Watch5 using "Wear OS Powered by Samsung".  Wear OS Powered by Samsung is not an Android operating system

Comment: @Hinte - I think it works but to confirm I have asked question. I am saying Googles wear OS app using android studio not just android os app.

Comment: @Hinte -- Of course the Galaxy Watch is run by **Android** Wear OS. https://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/galaxy-watch5/ "Powered by Samsung" just means the hardware.

Comment: @R15 -- I'm not sure whether I understand your scenario correctly. You want to be able to install your app twice and parallely? By BT/USB and via the Play Store? Or are you just interested to know whether both installation methods are applicable?

Comment: @Krokomot - I do not need both installation at a time. I was just wanted to know about the possible installation options. My main question is - Java Android studio's wear os app is supporting/installable in Samsung watch5 or not ?

Comment: Got it. Yes, it does. See my answer post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an Android Wear OS app created with Android Studio is installable and will support a Samsung Galaxy Watch of version 4+, i.e. also the Watch 5.

Samsung's official site on [developing apps for Galaxy Watch](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch) points in the main chapter "Develop Apps for Galaxy Watch" without further ado to [Principles of Wear OS development](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/principles)
 in the Android Developers Documentation as the starting point for further research. The Android Dev Docs as the *official* documentation for Android development, incl. Wear OS, are completely based on the default assumption of using the *official* Android Studio, including the provision of the corresponding downloads.

Your caution is reasonable as Samsung's Galaxy Watch series employed Tizen OS till Watch 3. However, since Galaxy Watch 4 Android Wear OS is used, as you can also see in this [overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Watch_series).

For Tizen devices one would use [Tizen Studio](https://docs.tizen.org/application/tizen-studio/), for the Android Wear devices [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio).

In short:

| Model | Year | OS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Watch | 2018 | Tizen |
| Watch Active | 2019 | Tizen |
| Watch Active 2 | 2019 | Tizen |
| Watch 3 | 2020 | Tizen |
| Watch 4 | 2021 | Android Wear |
| Watch 5 | 2022 | Android Wear |

Comment: One question, my app will be standalone, there wont be mobile app for the same (also watch will not be connected to mobile phone). Keeping these things in mind which watch should I purchase BT, LTE or 4G. These options are available when I purchase from Amazon ?

Comment: AFAK it's only BT vs LTE, also on Amazon India. But anyway, the question can also be extended to "BT-version with BT + Wifi vs. LTE-version vs BT + Wifi + Cellular GSM/HSPA/LTE" (note -- the LTE version is called "standalone" because it doesn't need a smartphone for a cellular connection as it has an own SIM-slot). Both versions are otherwise absolute identical. In your use case the BT-version would be enough (and cheaper). However, personally I -- as a dev -- would take the LTE-version. Who knows, maybe you will program an app next, where the Watch needs cellular capabilities.

Comment: Concerning the battery runtime both are identical, too, *if* you use them the same way. The LTE version will of cause last less, if you *do* use the cellular capabilities. If you don't, it won't.

Comment: Thank you. If I purchase LTE version now, in future if I need BT connection of watch with some sensors (or beacons devices), will it work or I will need to purchase new watch ? Can you suggest me a better option which works both ways ? As you mentioned in your comment -  BT + Wifi + Cellular GSM/HSPA/LTE. Which one should I purchase for all those options ?

Comment: LTE version unites all those connectivity abilities, including BT. You therefore won't need to purchase a new watch.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I noted a typo in my comment above. It's of course "(**BT-version** with BT + Wifi) vs (**LTE-version** with BT + Wifi + Cellular GSM/HSPA/LTE)". The additional "vs" instead of "with" after "LTE-version" might have caused confusion. I apologize.

Comment: Sorry for the TLDRs. So, in short -- *Now* you would only *need* the **BT-Version** for your current *particular* use case. If you want to be prepared for *all* use cases regarding connectivity you might meet in the future, you'll better invest in the **LTE-version**.

Comment: Glad to have helped you with this (bounty) question. In the next time I'll take also a look on your other bounty question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76480332/is-it-possible-to-connect-wear-app-with-beacons-devices.