# Is it possible to connect wear app with beacons devices

Tags: android, wear-os, apple-watch, ibeacon, beacon

I want to develop android wear smart watch app using android studio. My requirement is to talk wear app with located beacons devices. There will be multiple beacons devices for different locations in office. Whenever user (wearing watch) goes in the range fo beacons device signal, wear app should raise an event.

Wear app is not connected to mobile phone. It just standalone app. App should fire event even if watch display is off. Sometimes it happens if watch display if off it wont supply events. I probably use Samsung Watch5.

What configuration beacons device do I need to use/purchase when I use it Samsung Watch5 ?

Is that possible to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is achievable. Some links to useful, and reputable, sources:

In the Android Developer Documentation:

- The page on [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview) (BLE) is the starting point in the docs for BLE-related topics regarding Android, including Android Wear. As you know, beacons employ BLE.
- The guide on [Background Work Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) introduces the corresponding principles and forwards to further details, e.g. how to [Keep the device awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock).
- Though Android Wear OS is basically the same as the Android flavors used on other devices, there are some specifics. If necessary use the page on [Get started with Wear OS](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables) as the starting point for research.

Further you might be interested in the higher-level [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), including docs and sample code.

---

Regarding the beacon devices' configuration the only thing I can recommend for sure is to avoid second-hand Eddystone devices. Eddystone was discontinued by Google in 2018 as it had poor user popularity. So, though the Android Beacon Library still supports Eddystone, I wouldn't consider such devices for purchase. Otherwise you should be fine by sticking to the documentations mentioned above. I'm not aware of specifics considering the Galaxy Watch 5. However, I can't guarantee there isn't, so a separate question on [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) may help you.

You mentioned in the comments, that you plan to employ Estimote devices. Note, that Estimote applied as protocols -- if I'm not mistaken -- except of Estimote Monitoring also iBeacon and *Eddystone*. Better to keep away from latter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer its quite useful. Do you have idea what configuration beacons device I need to purchase when I use it with Samsung Watch5 ?

Comment: I think the only thing I would recommend for sure is to avoid second-hand Eddystone devices. Eddystone was discontinued by Google in 2018 as it had poor user popularity. So, though the Android Beacon Library still supports Eddystone, I wouldn't even think about purchasing such a device. Otherwise I think you will be fine by sticking to the documentations mentioned above. I'm not aware of specifics considering the Galaxy Watch 5. However, I can't guarantee there isn't. A separate question on [Android Enthusiasts Stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com) may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We are planning to go with Estimote beacons devices.

Comment: Now I get, why you didn't accept the answer yet... The part on configuration of beacons devices was missing. Sorry for the inconvenience. I updated with a part concerning Eddystone. Note also the last paragraph on Estimote.

Comment: Accepting answer is not going to make difference as I have already assigned you bounty .  _if I'm not mistaken -- except of Estimote Monitoring also iBeacon and Eddystone. Better to keep away from latter_ , are you saying Estimote is not that useful ? I am not that great at understanding English. Easy English I can understand properly.

Comment: That's a difficult question and depends on your requirements. In my subjective opinion the problem is that (1) the *Estimote Monitoring* is proprietary to Estimote only, (2) the *iBeacon* protocol is proprietary to Apple, however it can be used with Android (see e.g. this [article](https://www.ckhang.com/blog/2022/ibeacon-detection-with-android/) and [repository](https://github.com/tranchikhang/simple-ble-detection)) and (3) *Eddystone* can be considered as dead. Personally, my first choice would be a device supporting [AltBeacon](https://altbeacon.org/), but iBeacon would be OK, I think.

Comment: So, Estimote should be OK, if you stick to the iBeacon protocol.